# Python pandas matplotlib how to remove category labels in the plot?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, bar-chart

```
# Example Python program to plot a complex bar chart 

import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

 

# A python dictionary

data = {"Car Price":[24050, 34850, 38150],

        "Kerb Weight":[3045, 3572, 3638]

        };

index     = ["Variant1", "Variant2", "Variant3"];

 

# Dictionary loaded into a DataFrame       

dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=index);

 

# Draw a vertical bar chart

dataFrame.plot.bar(rot=15, title="Car Price vs Car Weight comparision for Sedans made by a Car Company");

plot.show(block=True);
```

This code is from https://pythontic.com/pandas/dataframe-plotting/bar%20chart

The result I would get is

[image]

How can I remove the category box in the top left corner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your second last line to this to remove the legend:

```
dataFrame.plot.bar(rot=15, title="Car Price vs Car Weight comparision for Sedans made by a Car Company", legend=False)
```